# Django object.filter(X__contains = 210922143300) gives error

Tags: python, django, contains

Please help me out

```
def search_venues(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       searched = request.POST['searched']
       titles = Information.objects.get(id=210922143300)
       print(titles)
       titles = Information.objects.filter(id__contains=21092214330)
       print (titles)
       return render(request,
                     'search_titles.html',
                     {'searched': searched, 'titles': titles})
    else:
       return render(request, 'search_titles.html', {})
```

the first print statement gives me: `<QuerySet [<Information: Wind energy can deliver vital slash to global warming>]>`, like i expect
the second print statement gives me: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc0RN.png)

What should i do, ofc in the future i want to pass my searched variable

Comment: you have a syntex error ```print (titles)```. fix it with ```print(titles)```

Comment: Aren't __contains is a string-search? And you give number to it. I think you should cast `titles = Information.objects.filter(id__contains=str(21092214330))`